# GORM Domain Mapping Issue

Tags: sql, grails, model, mapping, grails-orm

I've got a bit of a complicated domain model I'm trying to implement and I'm having some trouble. (On top of that, I'm quite new to all this!)

I have a User domain which has multiple roles and multiple tests. The Role domain works great. The Test domain is a bit more compilciated though because it requires two foreign keys instead of just 1 like in the Role domain. The first foreign key is the user_id and the second is a uni_id (university ID).

The User domain model contains the following

```
class User {

    static hasMany = [roles:Role, tests:Test]

    Integer userId
    ...

    static mapping = {
        table 'user_data'
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'userId', type: 'long'
        userId column: 'user_id'
        version false

        roles joinTable:[name:'user_role', key:'user_id']

        tests joinTable:[name:'user_test', key:'user_id'] // Here is where I run into trouble
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

The Test domain contains

```
class Test {

    static belongsTo = User
    static hasMany = [users:User]
    static hasOne = [uni:Uni]

    Integer testId // primary key
    String testType 

    static mapping = {
        table 'test'
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'testId', type: 'long'
        testId column: 'test_id'
        users joinTable:[name:'user_test', key:'test_id']
        uni joinTable:[name:'user_test', key:'test_id'] // If I leave this out, everything is groovy
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

and the Uni domain contains

```
class Uni {

    static belongsTo = Test
    static hasMany = [tests:Test]

    Integer uniId // primary key
    String shortName 
    String fullName 

    static mapping = {
        table 'uni'
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'uniId', type: 'long'
        uniId column: 'uni_id'
        version false

        tests joinTable:[name:'user_test', key:'uni_id']
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

If its not clear, what I'm trying to do is pull in the University ID, Test ID, and User ID to a table `user_test` to find based on the User ID which tests they have taken. Is there a simple way to do this?

The kinds of errors I'm getting lead me to believe that for some reason it is trying to perform all actions on the table `test` instead of `user_test`. For example,

```
Unsuccessful: alter table test add uni_id int not null
```

I'd like to be able to access the test and university information corresonding to the specific user via `user.tests.testType` and `user.tests.uni.fullName` or something to that extent. What am I doing wrong? More importantly, is there a better way to do this?! Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: something interesting I just thought of.. a user can have multiple tests, but the inverse isn’t true.  A given test will never be shared among multiple people. So I think that changes things a bit.. I'll do some reading and post if I come up with anything new.

Edit 2: Here's the Role domain

```
class Role {

  static belongsTo = User
  static hasMany = [users:User]

  Integer roleId
  String shortName
  String roleName
  Integer roleLevel

  static mapping = {
    table 'role'
    id generator: 'assigned', name: 'roleId', type: 'long'
    roleId column: 'role_id'
    users joinTable:[name:'user_role', column:'user_id', key:'role_id']
    version false
  }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Edit 3: I am now trying to store all test information in the Test domain model and simply choose the Uni name to store as a field in Test, but am getting weird errors when I try this. My new files look like this

```
class User {

    static hasMany = [roles:Role, tests:Test]

    Integer userId

    static mapping = {
        table 'user_data'
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'userId', type: 'long'
        userId column: 'user_id'
        version false

        roles joinTable:[name:'user_role', key:'user_id']
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

and

```
class Test {

    static belongsTo = User

    Integer testId // primary key
    Integer testTypeId
    String testTypeName
    String testUni
    Date testDate

    static mapping = {
        table 'test'
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'testId', type: 'long'
        testId column: 'test_id'
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

but now I'm getting the following error when I try to run it `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Missing type or column for column[tests_test] on domain[User] referencing[Test]`

Any idea what that's about?

Comment: Where is the code for the Role domain class?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa see edit 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got everything working (after a bit of modification in terms of the domain model)

```
class User {

    static hasMany = [roles:Role, tests:Test]

    Integer userId

    static mapping = {
        table 'user_data'
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'userId', type: 'long'
        userId column: 'user_id'
        version false

        roles joinTable:[name:'user_role', column:'role_id', key:'user_id']
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

and

```
class Test {

    User user
    Integer testId // primary key
    String testType
    String testUni
    Date testDate

    static mapping = {
        table 'test'
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'testId', type: 'long'
        testId column: 'test_id'
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

with

```
class Uni {

    Integer uniId // primary key
    String shortName 
    String fullName 

    static mapping = {
        table 'uni'
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'uniId', type: 'long'
        uniId column: 'uni_id'
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

So now what I'm doing is selecting the university from a drop down tab in my GSP and just saving it in Test as the string testUni. Then, the big change was removing all joinTables between the three and adding `User user` to Test. I'm still a little fuzzy on why what I was doing before didn't work, but I won't complain about a working app!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, one issue you have is that you're trying to share the User-to-Test association join table with the Test-to-Unit association. That's not going to work.

Lets look at it in database terms. I'm not an ASCII art expert, so I hope this diagram doesn't make your eyes bleed.

```
user_data (userId) |---|< (user_id) user_test (test_id) >|---| (testId) test
```

The diagram above shows the database implementation of the many-to-many association between the User and Test domain classes. You can see that the *user_data.userId* links to *user_test.user_id* and *user_test.test_id* links to *test.testId*.

Now here's where it starts to get weird. There are two different associations between Test and Uni: a bidirectional one-to-one and a one-to-many. I just don't understand that. But I want to illustrate an important issue with your join tables, so here it is.

```
test (testId) |---|< (test_id) user_test (uni_id) >|---| (uniId) uni
```

Because you're using the same join table (user_test) for two different associations you're asking GORM to create a table like this:

```
USER_TEST
- USER_ID
- TEST_ID
- UNIT_ID
```

GORM won't do that because join tables are supposed to have only two fields. Not only that, but also you're defining a many-to-many in database terms, and yet a bidirectional one-to-one and a one-to-many in GORM terms. Ouch!

## TODO

The first change I recommend is to use a different join table for the Test-Uni association.

Comment: I have scratched the need for a join table for the Test-Uni association, but have stumbled upon a new error! Check out edit 3

Comment: Are User, Role, and Test all located within the grails-app/domain/ directory?

Comment: They are. I've got it working now and I'll post what I did in a 4th edit

Comment: Great! I'd like to see how it turned out.